# Disable DHCP on airport when it's an Access Point

Tags: dhcp, airport

I have airport access points that are linked to my main router. I set up DHCP on the router and I just want to use the airport as an access point, but if I put it in this mode it enables DHCP by default.

Is there a way to disable DHCP while on this mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Put it in bridge mode.

AirPort base stations have 3 modes for sharing their Internet connection:

1. NAT + DHCP server (share a single IP address)
2. Bridge + DHCP server (share a range)
3. Bridge only

You want "Bridge only".